# can DataFrames have "holes" and how to implement it?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Talking about pandas we can have a DataFrame of the form

```
      ao    a1    a2
1    2.3    3.4    2.1
2    3.1    2.1    2.2
3    3.4    4.5    3.3
```

but is it possible to have something like

```
      ao    a1    a2
1    2.3    3.4    2.1
2           2.1    2.2
3    3.4           3.3
```

meaning no values (holes) inside the DataFrame?

How can I achieve something like this?
(My plan is later I will plot this including plotting nothing in the holes)

Comment: Does `numpy.nan` meet your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to use `NaN` ?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a0': [2.3, np.nan, 3.4],
                   'a1': [3.4, 2.1, np.nan],
                   'a2': [2.1, 2.2, 3.3]})

print(df)
```

Output

```
    a0   a1   a2
0  2.3  3.4  2.1
1  NaN  2.1  2.2
2  3.4  NaN  3.3
```